# How do I use rvest to sort text into different columns?

Tags: r, rvest

I am using `rvest` to (try to) scrape all the author affiliation data from a database of academic publications called RePEc. I have the authors' short IDs, which I'm using to scrape affiliation data. However, each time I try, it gives me the 404 error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404`

It must be an issue with my use of `sapply` because when I test it using an individual ID, it works. Here is the code I'm using:

```
df$author_reg <- c("paa6","paa2","paa1", "paa8", "pve266", "pya500")

df$websites <- paste0("https://ideas.repec.org/e/", df$author_reg, ".html")

df$affiliation <- sapply(df$websites, function(x) try(x %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("#affiliation h3") %>% html_text()))
```

I actually need to do this for six columns of authors and there are `NA` values I'd like to skip so if anyone knows how to do that as well, I would be enormously grateful (but not a big deal if I not). Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: I have just discovered that the error is in the formula for the websites. Sometimes it should be `df$websites <- paste0("https://ideas.repec.org/e/", df$author_reg, ".html")` and sometimes it should be `df$websites <- paste0("https://ideas.repec.org/f/", df$author_reg, ".html")`

Does anyone know how to get R to try both and give me the one that works?

Comment: with the example you provided, i don't get the error...

Comment: I've realised that the formula is wrong. Sometimes it should be "https://ideas.repec.org/e/" and sometimes it should be "https://ideas.repec.org/f/". Any idea how I can get it to try both?

Comment: There is a tryCatch mechanism. Many answered questions on SO.

Comment: Ok i write something below for you.. try and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the two links and use `try` on bottom of them. I am assuming there is only 1 that would give a valid website. Otherwise we can always edit the code to take in everything that works:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

df = data.frame(id=1:6)

df$author_reg <- c("paa6","paa2","paa1", "paa8", "pve266", "pya500")
http1 <- "https://ideas.repec.org/e/"
http2 <- "https://ideas.repec.org/f/"

df$affiliation <- sapply(df$author_reg, function(x){
  links = c(paste0(http1, x, ".html"),paste0(http2, x, ".html"))

# here we try both links and store under attempt
  attempts = links %>% map(function(i){
    try(read_html(i) %>% html_nodes("#affiliation h3") %>% html_text())
  })

# the good ones will have "character" class, the failed ones, try-error
  gdlink = which(sapply(attempts,class) != "try-error")
  if(length(gdlink)>0){
  return(attempts[[gdlink[1]]])
  }
  else{
  return("True 404 error")
  }
})
```

Check the results:

```
 df
  id author_reg
1  1       paa6
2  2       paa2
3  3       paa1
4  4       paa8
5  5     pve266
6  6     pya500
                                                                                                                   affiliation
1                                                                                   Statistisk SentralbyråGovernment of Norway
2                                                              Department of EconomicsCollege of BusinessUniversity of Wyoming
3 (80%) Institutt for ØkonomiUniversitetet i Bergen, (20%) Gruppe for trygdeøkonomiInstitutt for ØkonomiUniversitetet i Bergen
4                                                                       Centraal Planbureau (CPB)Government of the Netherlands
5                   Department of FinanceRotterdam School of Management (RSM Erasmus University)Erasmus Universiteit Rotterdam
6                                                                            Business SchoolSwinburne University of Technology
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this but unfortunately it's giving me an error message: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, affiliation, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 88821" I've add more entries to the df$author_reg above that include the different website format.. Sorry should have done that earlier

Comment: hey, i tried your example, it works for me. I could see that the first 4 uses "e" and last 2 uses "f'. You can see the updated answer

Comment: Hey, OK so I reconstructed the dataframe because I figured that could be an issue and it's now working better but I'm getting this error: "Error in attempts[[gdlink]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index" I think (not sure) that there are 3 dead links. Is there anything I can add to this code for when there's a true 404 error?

Comment: Ok so, that error is you have more than 1 good link.. and yes you right about situations when there is no good link, i.e true 404 error. What would you do if both "e" and "f" works?

Comment: OK cool - I think this is like 3 or 4 entries so can I just use try or tryCatch to skip these ones (I'll do them manually)? If so, where would i put it?

Comment: if both links work, they should be the same right? you can just return one of them? Ok try edited answer.. if there's a true 404 it returns it. Else it chooses  the first (of 1 or 2) that works

Comment: Yeah, I've figured out what needs to be done so this is perfect! Thanks!